# Lowest Cost non-bipartite assignment problem

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, variable-assignment, graph-theory

Any ideas of how to implement an efficient algorithm (better than O(n<sup>2</sup>)) to solve the assignment problem in a non-bipartite graph?

The main idea is the following:

I have two identical sets, lets say `S1 = [A,B,C,D]`, and `S2 = [A,B,C,D]`, and there are some edges between different elements of the sets, with a given cost, e.g. `A->B (cost 4)`, `B->C (cost 3)`,  `C->A (cost 10)`, `D->A (cost 6)`.

I want to find the best assignation such that: the amount of assigned elements is maximum with the lowest total cost. (The amount of assigned elements is more important).

So for this example, the best assignation would be:

```
A->D (cost 6)  
B->C (cost 3)
```

`[A,B,C,D]` where assigned and the cost is minimum: 9

Another one, but not the best would be:

```
A->B (cost 4)
```

The rest cannot be assigned caused `A` has already been assigned, thus the assignation is not the maximum as possible

I've designed a greedy solution in O(n<sup>2</sup>) that is too slow.

The size of the sets is usually small (5-10) elements.

Comment: What's the significance of having two sets?

Comment: Your costs list does not match the assignations in your examples. Perhaps some explanation is missing

Comment: You're right (erasing mistake :P). I've just edited the cost list

Comment: How O(n^2) for 4 or 5 item is slow?

Comment: Because there can be many edges connecting the nodes (elements). Also, the algorithm is executed many times (many different assignments are required), which in sum makes the O(n^2) to affect the general performance

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you have an undirected graph and you want to select a maximal number of edges such that no two edges are incident on the same node (node = set element in your description).  You also want to break ties using minimal total cost of the selected edges.  Let me know if this doesn't fit what you're asking for.

Create the dual graph of the one above (one node for each original edge, two nodes are connected if the corresponding original edges are incident to the same vertex).  You are then looking for a [maximum independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_problem) of the dual nodes.  That's an NP-hard problem, unfortunately.  And that's just for the maximum count of edges, it's probably slightly harder to break ties using weights.  Luckily for you, your N is 5-10 so you may be able to brute force it.

Comment: Yep, the problem is more or like you describe it. It is definitely NP-hard, when thinking of it as the maximum independent set problem. I wanted to know if there were any other solution smarter than my sort of "constrained brute force", that avoids the adaptation to another NP-hard problem, given the small amount of nodes. Thx for your answer

Comment: Your proof that this is NP-hard is wrong. You don't prove NP-hardness by reducing the problem to an NP-hard problem, you prove it by reducing an NP-hard problem to the problem you're trying to solve. Also, if I understand the question correctly this isn't NP-hard.

Comment: You're right, that's not a proof-providing reduction direction.  I never claimed it was.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a maximum non-bipartite matching: [1](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~karp/greatalgo/lecture05.pdf), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm).

The algorithm is pretty difficult to implement and I haven't seen any implementations around, especially if you want the minimum cost. For such small input, you're better off brute forcing it in my opinion.

How did you solve it with a greedy algorithm? Are you sure it works?

Comment: IVlad is right here. Greedy approaches normally do not work for this one. bipartite matching is very similar to the maximum flow problem.

Comment: I've checked Edmond's algorithm. It is quite difficult to implement indeed. I didn't try it because the greedy solution was giving acceptable results... Although the graph size is small, I have to calculate the assignment plenty of times, so brute force is just to heavy. The greedy solution does not always calculate the best assignment, but it does give acceptable solutions. Thx